# AWS Beanstalk Auto-scaling Scaling Triggers with HealthyHostCount or UnhealthyHost count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

I have Elastic Beanstalk Environment , I need to setup autoscaling policy like if Elastic Loadbalancer has Unhealthy instance it will bring up new instance The Policy I used right now is below

[image: My configuration]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change that first option "HealthyInstanceCount" to UnHealthyInstanceCount and if there's 1 or more unhealthy, add +1 instance. If UnHealthyInstanceCount is 0, add -1 instance (take one away). Make sure your minimum is set to 1 or more (it is recommended 2 minimum, in two separate availability zones for High Availability).

[image]

Comment: many Thanks Max. here what I did Please let me know all option are fineTrigger measurement: UnhealthHostCount
Trigger statistic: Maximum
Unit of measurement: Count 
Measurement period (minutes): 5 
Breach duration (minutes): 5
Upper threshold: 1
Upper breach scale increment: -1
Lower threshold: 0
Lower breach scale increment: 1

Comment: Swap the lower breach scale increment and upper breach scale increment. If there are >=1 Unhealthy server, you want to _add_ more (+1). If you have 0 unhealthy servers, you want to _remove_ servers (-1)

Comment: here what I did Now Please let me know all option are fineTrigger measurement: UnhealthHostCount Trigger statistic: Maximum Unit of measurement: Count Measurement period (minutes): 5 Breach duration (minutes): 5 Upper threshold: 1 Upper breach scale increment: 1 Lower threshold: 0 Lower breach scale increment: -1

Comment: I think its good. Now you can test it! SSH into the instance and manually stop nginx (`sudo service nginx stop`) and it'll become unhealthy in the load balancer. You should see a scale up after 5 minutes

Comment: Hi Max,  what shall you do to repair the instance you stop its nginx later?  Shall you issue a nginx start command to invoke it again otherwise what happen to the instance ?   How to start nginx in EC2 ?

Comment: Using this approach, Elastic Beanstalk will constantly and in every 5 mins either adds one instance or takes down one instance unless it reaches the min or max instance count. Is this an issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Following up on this as I just had the same problem. The solution proposed by @Max is on the right track, but a slight tweak on the numbers is needed.

1) Ensure minimum instance count and maximum instance count are set as precautions

2) Set the following parameters
Trigger Measurement: UnHealthyHostCount
Trigger statistic: Maximum
Unit of measurement: Count
Upper threshold: 0
Upper breach scale increment: 1
Lower threshold: 1
Lower breach scale increment: -1

Answer (score 2):

The scaling triggers in `EB console > Configuration > Capacity` are a bit limited in the sense there is no option for `<=` and `>=`. To get full control of the triggers, go to `AWS Console > EC2 > Auto Scaling Groups`.

There select your Beanstalk app's Auto Scaling group (If you can't recognize your beanstalk app's Auto Scaling group then here is a tip: By default, the auto scaling group will be named in this fashion `awseb-e-<Environment ID>-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-XXXXXXXXXXX`. You can find our your beanstalk app's Environment ID from the app's dashboard)

On selection of the Auto Scaling group of your app, select `Scaling Policies` at the bottom. There you can read, in plain english, your triggers for upscaling and downscaling.

You will notice 2 policies of the form `awseb-e-<Environment ID>-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-YYYYYYYYYY` and `awseb-e-<Environment ID>-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-ZZZZZZZZZZ`. For each policy, there will be a CloudWatch alarm, of the form `awseb-e-<Environment ID>-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarm***-AAAAAAAAAA`, asscociated as trigger.

Then if you want to fine tune the trigger, go to AWS CloudWatch > Alarms and select your alarm. Here you will get **a lot more options to edit your triggers**. You can select thresholds such as `<=` and `>=` and add SNS topics etc. A lot more options.

Edit, and Update Alarm and go back to your Auto Scaling Group's Scaling policies. You will see the new updates there, again in plain English and very easy to follow and understand.